# JunOS Regular Expressions for AS Path

Tags: regex, bgp

I want to write a regex in Juniper MX960 router for BGP including 3 AS paths with first element is constant, second and third are wildcard. I found that we can put as numbers manually like this:

`9121+ (one|two|three|...) (one|two|three|...)`

This doesn't work for me 'cause I don't know whole as numbers in second and third level. They can be anything. I want them to be "any".

`9121+ any+ any+` « I need this.

Answer (score 1):

the exact answer may depend on the version of Junos that you are using.

However, this syntax should work:

```
show route aspath-regex 9121 (.*){2}
```

This means, match AS9121 as the first element, and then any AS number exactly two times.

Here there is a lot of good examples:

http://www.juniper.net/techpubs/en_US/junos15.1/topics/usage-guidelines/policy-configuring-as-path-regular-expressions-to-use-as-routing-policy-match-conditions.html

Answer (score -1):

How about "9121 . ."? It seems to me like that may work.